# Is it legal c++ to use reference as array/pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

My team (including myself) is new to C++. A piece of our new development is a C++ function that needs to interface with a C function that takes an array as input. Something like the following construct was made to achieve this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void the_c_function(double *array, int len)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      printf("%d: %g\n", i, array[i]);
   }
}

void the_cpp_wrapper(double& dref, int len)
{
   the_c_function(&dref, len);
}

int main()
{
   const int LEN = 4;
   double dbl_array[LEN] = { 3,4,5,6 };
   the_cpp_wrapper(dbl_array[0], LEN);
   return 0;
}
```

When compiled, this works as expected: it prints the contents of the array:

```
0: 3
1: 4
2: 5
3: 6
```

But this feels hardly legal to me or at the best something that should be discouraged.

Is this legal C++, i.e. is it guaranteed that a pointer to a reference of an array points to the original array?

Is there any reason why one would do it like this instead of using a pointer directly instead of using the reference as inbetween?

Comment: That's not a pointer to a reference. You can't take a pointer to a reference. `&some_ref` where `some_ref` is a reference creates a pointer to whatever the reference refers to.

Comment: (I don't know why you're bothering - your C++ can call `the_c_function` directly without going through `the_cpp_wrapper`.)

Comment: I believe this code is legal, but you shouldn't use it.  Instead, use something like `template <std::size_t N> void the_cpp_wrapper(double (&arr)[N]) { the_c_function(arr, N); }`

Comment: @NathanOliver: That just forces the length to be compile-time constant without a clear reason.

Comment: `dref` is not a reference to an array, it's a reference to a `double`. `&dref` is the location of that `double`. If the referenced `double` happens to be the first element of an array, `&dref` is of course the location of the first element of that array. (And, as has been noted already, this whole dance is totally unnecessary - just do `the_c_function(dbl_array, LEN)`.)

Comment: I fail to see what the point of this is. Why not call the C function directly? If you want to convert to C++, then you might use a vector, in which case it makes sense to have that wrapper.

Comment: It is perfectly legit to take the address of a reference/alias. The confusing part, at least initially for me, is that the '&' is overloaded -- in one case it used as a declaration of a reference and in the other it is the traditional "address of" operator borrowed from C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of code readability aside,

> *is it guaranteed that a pointer to a reference of an array points to the original array?*

Yes, see [§ 5.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#5) Expressions:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis. The expression **designates the object or function denoted by the reference**, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

And [§8.3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.decl#dcl.ref-5) References:

> 4   It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage.
>
> 5   There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and **no pointers to references**.

In other words, an "address of a reference" isn't a thing; given `double& dref`, taking an address `&dref` will give the address of the original element inside the array.

Answer (score 5):

> My team (including myself) is new to C++. ...
>
> [...]
>
> ... something that should be discouraged.

You should get in the habit now of using the Standard C++ Library, in your case the best choice is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib>
#include <vector>

void the_c_function(const double *array, size_t len) {/*...*/}
void the_cpp_wrapper(const std::vector<double>& v)
{
   the_c_function(v.data(), v.size());
}
// ----------------------------
int main()
{
   const std::vector<double> dbl_array { 3,4,5,6 };
   the_cpp_wrapper(dbl_array);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You also should be clearer about `const double*` vs. `double*`, C++ intentionally wants you to use a much more verbose `const_cast<double*>` to cast-away `const`-ness.

If you want to go "all in" with C++, you can make `the_cpp_wrapper()` a bit more generic with a template:

```
template<typename TSpan>
void the_cpp_wrapper(const TSpan& v)
{
   the_c_function(v.data(), v.size());
}
```

With this code, you can pass anything to `the_cpp_wrapper` that has `data()` and `size()` methods.

---

Not directly related, but you'll probably find [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) useful too.

Comment: This is some good information, but doesn't really answer the question. Taking the address of a reference/alias is fine -- your are just simply taking the address of the thing being refererenced/alias. I think what is confusing is the overloaded use of the '&' -- in one case it is used to declare a reference and in the other is is being used as an "address of"" operator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is legal and it is guaranteed to reference to the original element in the array based on your code.

Some people like to design interface to force the caller to pass by reference to avoid checking whether the argument is a `NULL` pointer, which might be required when passing by pointer.